# Test custom function in Form1

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some unit tests that successfully test functions in other classes added to the overall project. I cannot seem to "see" any functions that I add in `Form1` on in any additional files that are partial classes `From1:form`.

The function I want to test is modified `internal`. I HAVE added `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Tests")]` to the file Properties -> AssemblyInfo.cs

What am I doing wrong?

My function to test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Accord.Collections;
using System.IO;
using Accord.Math;
using g = GeometRi;
using msf = System.Math;


namespace ProcessPointsCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    internal List<Point> FindPointsInCapsule(
        List<NodeDistance<KDTreeNode<Point>>> points,
        Point searchPoint,
        Axis axis,
        double width = 0,
        double radius = 0.03,
        double bandwidth = 0.005
        )
    {
        g.Point3d lowerPoint = new Point();
        g.Point3d upperPoint = new Point();
        g.Segment3d centerLine;
        double innerRadius = radius - bandwidth;

        switch (axis)
        {
            case Axis.x:
                lowerPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X - (width / 2), searchPoint.Y, searchPoint.Z);
                upperPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X + (width / 2), searchPoint.Y, searchPoint.Z);
                break;
            case Axis.y:
                lowerPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X, searchPoint.Y - (width / 2), searchPoint.Z);
                upperPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X, searchPoint.Y + (width / 2), searchPoint.Z);
                break;
            case Axis.z:
                lowerPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X, searchPoint.Y, searchPoint.Z - (width / 2));
                upperPoint = new Point(searchPoint.X, searchPoint.Y, searchPoint.Z + (width / 2));
                break;
        }

        centerLine = new g.Segment3d(lowerPoint, upperPoint);

        List<Point> results = new List<Point>();
        foreach(NodeDistance<KDTreeNode<Point>> kv in points)
        {
            if(centerLine.DistanceTo(kv.Node.Value) > innerRadius && centerLine.DistanceTo(kv.Node.Value) < radius)
            {
                results.Add(kv.Node.Value);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

My test file:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using g = GeometRi;
using Accord.Collections;
using ProcessPointsCSharp;
using Helpers;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CapsuleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            KDTree<Point> tree = new KDTree<Point>(3);

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { -0.30652008, 0.39502587, 0.00 },
                new Point(-0.30652008, 0.39502587, 0.00)
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 0, 0, 0, },
                new Point(0, 0, 0)
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 0.45, 0.31819805, 0.31819805 },
                new Point( 0.45, 0.31819805, 0.31819805 )
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 2.00723708, 0.37538366, 0.33028338 },
                new Point(2.00723708, 0.37538366, 0.33028338)
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 0.25, 0.1767767, 0.1767767 },
                new Point(0.25, 0.1767767, 0.1767767)
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 3.59315974, 1.32408059, 0.00 },
                new Point(3.59315974, 1.32408059, 0.00)
                );

            tree.Add(
                new double[] { 5.41553352 , -0.23012364 , 0.00 },
                new Point(5.41553352, -0.23012364, 0.00)
                );

            var points = tree.Nearest(new double[] { 0,0,0}, 100);

            Assert.AreEqual(7, points.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to clean your test project and rebuild

Comment: The `CapsuleTest` has nothing to do with `Form1` in the question. Why has that been included in the question?